# I am confused by this FFT equation

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

Hello i am reading a paper talking about creating a height field using two DFTs (or rather FFTs).

It generates frequencies and produces a height field with respect to time. So the equation i presume is actually an inverse FFT.

What i don't understand is why there is no division for the final result that is normally shown for inverse FFT.

This is the paper:
[https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~jtessen/reports/papers_files/coursenotes2004.pdf](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Ejtessen/reports/papers_files/coursenotes2004.pdf)

The relevant equation and information:

[image]

Since this is going from frequency to time domain, then its an iFFT so why is there not a coefficient of $1/(NM)$ before it... is there some cancellation that happens in the case of 2 dimensions?

I ask this because this page says the inverse FFT has such a division: https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/IFFT-vs-FFT.html

[image]

I am self taught on this stuff so go easy on me, i'm not a math expert - i've been trying to decipher this math for over a week so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Please note that we are dealing with a Fourier Transform (FT), not an FFT which is an algorithm to compute it. Also, the transform is from *space* to *spatial frequency*, and not time/frequency.

Having said that, you are formally correct, however many times authors (especially in physics) are a bit sloppy in the normalization and might ignore the $1\over MN$ term until they need to apply the inverse. You can think of it as a *definition* of $\tilde h(\bf{k},t)$. The author calls them Fourier components, and they are, up to the normalization factor. The difference from a true Fourier component becomes apparent if you naively try to perform a FT on $h(\bf{x},t)$, but if you remember the definition (equation 36), you can get the normalization right.

Comment: Are you sure its not the inverse? The paper generates frequencies and then converts to a height map as an ocean surface on a 2D mesh - isn't that frequency domain to time domain which means he would use the iFFT? Plus why does the paper show a positive complex number for exponential if its not the iFFT ?
And if so why would they ignore `1/MN` would that just mean it is simply wrong ? Why can they get away with not doing normalisation ?

Comment: After rereading, I think you are correct. I will edit my answer

Comment: Hmm you mention i can get the normalisation right, i am not sure what you mean by this ? Are you saying the h(k,t) function already has normalisation so they skip the normalisation after the iFFT is complete?

Comment: I mean that you are free to define $\tilde h(\bf{k},t)$ any way you like, do any calculations you like etc, but when you want to compute the value via FT, you need to remember that you didn't normalize.

Comment: Sure - i am just curious why the paper doesn't normalise or at least doesn't mention it..its what got me confused on whether it was inverse or not.

Comment: The inverse FT and the FT are morally the same.